# Buscar el numero menor de un objeto de datos, con diversas condiciones

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Tengo una arreglo de datos el cual extraigo de un base de datos, como el que se muestra a continuación. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiero es asignar a uno de los ID_SERVICIOS (rojo), una de las ID_UNIDAD, sin que estas unidades se repitan, y que cumplan con ser la distanciaKM menor.

El resultado que esperaria es el siguiente:
**0: serv: ID_SERVICIOS 115 con tra:ID_UNIDAD 1 
1: serv: ID_SERVICIOS 116 con tra:ID_UNIDAD 14
2: serv: ID_SERVICIOS 117 con tra:ID_UNIDAD 17**

Primero intente comparar este arreglo para obtener aquellos que tienen la misma unidad asignada y compara la distancia que tienen para asignar solo aquella que sea la menor:

> ```
>         const { dataDistServ } = this.state;
> ```

```
        for (var i = 0; i < dataDistServ.length; i++) {
          for (var j = i + 1; j < dataDistServ.length; j++) {
            if (dataDistServ[i].serv.ID_SERVICIOS !== dataDistServ[j].serv.ID_SERVICIOS
              && dataDistServ[i].tra.ID_UNIDAD === dataDistServ[j].tra.ID_UNIDAD) {
              console.log( "Servicio i :" + dataDistServ[i].serv.IDSERVICIO + ' Servicio j:' + dataDistServ[j].serv.IDSERVICIO );
              console.log(dataDistServ[i].tra.ID_UNIDAD + 'Tracto');
            }
          };
      }
```

como resultado tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres hacer? puedes por favor decirnos qué has intentado hasta ahora, y explicarnos cual es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Hola @GermanAlzate Ya he modificado mi pregunta.!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ir guardando los datos que te sirven. para asi cuando leas los datos puedes compararlo con los valores que vas sacando.
Con el metodo `map()` leemos todo el array y vamos seleccionando cual se repite y cual no, algo asi:

```
let array = [];
objeto.map((e, i) => {
  let flag = false;
  array.map((f, j) => {
    if (f.serv.ID_UNIDAD == e.serv.ID_UNIDAD)
      flag = true;
  })
  if (!flag) {
    array.push(e);
  }

});
```

pruebalo, no estoy seguro de que funcione ese codigo